# How to create geo replication for azure SQL using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database

I have gone through the python azure SDK documentation. But I cannot able to find any modules that can be used to create sql geo replication.

I can find powershell commands to create geo replication. But I need it in python.

Thanks

Comment: You can use REST API from Python. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/

Answer (score 0):

Creating a geo secondary database is done using the create database API. An example of the REST API for this is below:

```
{
  "location": "southeastasia",
  "sku": {
    "name": "S0",
    "tier": "Standard"
  },
  "properties": {
    "createMode": "Secondary",
    "sourceDatabaseId": "/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/Default-SQL-NorthEurope/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testsvr1/databases/testdb"
  }
}
```

(From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate#creates_a_database_as_an_on-line_secondary. )

This is accessible in the Python SDK (azure-mgmt-sql) like this:

```
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.sql import SqlManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.sql.models import CreateMode

RESOURCE_GROUP = 'YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME'
LOCATION = 'eastus'  # example Azure availability zone, should match resource group
SQL_SERVER = 'yourvirtualsqlserver'
SQL_DB = 'YOUR_SQLDB_NAME'

sql_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(SqlManagementClient)

# Create a SQL database in the Basic tier
database = sql_client.databases.create_or_update(
    RESOURCE_GROUP,
    SQL_SERVER,
    SQL_DB,
    {
        'location': LOCATION,
        'create_mode': CreateMode.secondary.value,
        'source_database_id': '/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/Default-SQL-NorthEurope/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testsvr1/databases/testdb'
    }
)
```